# Autolayout , UITableView inside UiScrollView don't grow

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I had this structure on my storyboard (i have added some example name to easly understand):

- **UIView** (the main view) "BlackView"

  -**UIScrollView** (inside the main view) "OrangeView"

  - **UIView** "YelloView" (ContentView inside main scroll)

    - **UITableView** "BluView" (Inside and on the top of the contentView)
    - **UIView** "RedView" (Inside of the ContentView and on the same level of UITableview)

What i wanna achive? I want a table that grow proportionally to his rows number (the row height is fixed to 60). I also want an UIScrollview that grow in content_size and scroll ability accordingly to the heights sum of the BlueView and the RedView.

The autolayout constraints are:

**UiScrollView "OrangeView":** (top 0,trailing 0,bottom 0,leading 0)

**UIView "YelloView":** (top 0,trailing 0,bottom 0,leading 0) (equal width to main ed equal height to main "BlackView" , priority “low” for bottom)

**UITabelView "BluView":** (top 0,trailing 0,leading 0)

**UIView "RedView":** (Vertical space 2 to "BluView",trailing 0,leading 0,bottom 0 to YelloView)

I have a complete chain of constraints from top to bottom of the view. UITableView is free to grow because i haven't set directly his "height" constraint and uitableview setscrollingenabled is FALSE. The result is a tableview that don't grow.

I can produce the growing by code:

```
Table.frame=CGRectMake(BluView.frame.origin.x, BluView.frame.origin.y, BluView.frame.size.width, BluView.contentSize.height);
```

I works, the table frame and the "OrangeView" scroll content_size grow correctly but "RedView" doesn't respond to this frame change and it doesn't move to the new "table bottom" ad 2 of distance.

What i have already tried to refresh the constraints system:

```
    [BlackView layoutIfNeeded];
    [BlackView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [RedView layoutIfNeeded];
    [ScrollContainer layoutIfNeeded];
    [RedView layoutIfNeeded];
    [RedView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [OrangeView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [RedView updateConstraints];
    [OrangeView updateConstraints];
    [BlackView updateConstraints];
    [BluView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [RedView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

I have called those methods before and after the uitable frame change, they doesn't refresh the RedView's y position. How i can obtain the desired behaviour? There's a way to create anothere type of "costraints tree" or maybe there's another way to refresh the position of the RedView after i have programmatically change the Tableview frame?

Answer (score 1):

> UITableView is free to grow because i haven't set directly his "height" constraint and uitableview setscrollingenabled is FALSE.

Setting `setscrollingenabled` to false doesn't tell the tableView to have the height of its content, it just disables the scroll behavior. So if your tableView is 200pt tall and you have a content of 500pt, you'll never see the 300pt at the bottom.

Add a height constraint to your tableView and update its constant with the tableView's `contentSize.height` every time the `contentSize` changes.
This way it will always have the size of its content, and because it's in a scrollView you'll still be able to scroll to see all the content.

PS: The yellow view is useless here if it's only a container for the blue and red views.

Comment: I have given height constraint, top, bottom, leading and trailing as well. still the table view is growing beyond its limits as it has the content.

Comment: You can't force the tableView's contentSize to match the bounds defined by the constraints. Bounds and contentSize are two unrelated properties.

Comment: It was working fine until i made the tableview as subview of the scroll view. After I made it subview to scroll view then it started over lapping with the above view. Before that it was as expected.